# Sharepoint - How to Conditional Date Stamp a column when status is changed

Tags: sharepoint

I have sharepoint online I have list with two columns. First column is STATUS (choice type = New, in progression, finish) Second column is Completion Date (date type). I need automatic fill Completion Date field When i choose FINISH in Status column the system should automatic fill  with today's date. Can anyone Please help...

Regards,
SK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can achieve this by integrating a Power Automate Flow like below with your list.
[image]

I used the formula `formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')` to set today's date to Completion Date field in the Update item action.
[image]

Test result in my list. If I created an item(set Status to FINISH) or modify an item(change STATUS from START to FINISH), the Completion Date field will be set to today's date.
[image]